# Cause of overflow when scrolling a table with fixed first column and first row of HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

### Problem

When I scroll a table with a fixed first column and first row in HTML, the scrolled column overtakes the first column and protrudes, as shown in the image below.

---

[image]

---

```css
table.crossLine td:nth-of-type(2n-1){
    background: whitesmoke;
}

.rowFixed {
    position: sticky; 
    top:      0;     
    z-index: 100;
}

.colFixed {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 101;

}

.fixed {
    position: sticky;
    top:      0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 102; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%; overflow:scroll;">
            <table class="table table-bordered text-nowrap crossLine" style="table-layout: fixed" >
                <thead class="thead-light bg-danger">
                <tr>
                    <th class="xl65 bg-light fixed" style="height:15pt;width:120px;"></th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">1</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">2</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">3</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">4</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">5</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">6</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">7</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">8</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">9</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger rowFixed" style="width:45px; ">10</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th class="bg-danger colFixed" style="height:15pt;">A</th>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                    <td style="width:40px;" >0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

---

### Question

Why does it stick out after scrolling?

Can you advise us to investigate the cause?
Is there a problem with the way the CSS is written?

Comment: Can you post your html also?

Comment: sory. Due to character limit, html could not be posted. Instead, shortened html was posted.

Comment: You can reduce it by removing the inline styles and defining it in your css